# Starting OCaml development and facing some hiccups

Tags: ocaml

I am reading [Real World OCaml](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144932391X) and working through some of the exercises.

I wrote this program as given in the book:

```
open Core.Std

let build_counts() = 
    In_channel.fold_lines stdin ~init:[] ~f:(fun counts line -> 
        let count = 
            match List.Assoc.find counts line with
            | None -> 0
            | Some x -> x
        in
        List.Assoc.add counts line (count + 1)
    )

let () = 
    build_counts()
    |> List.sort ~cmp:(fun (_, x) (_, y) -> Int.descending x y)
    |> (fun l -> List.take l 10)
    |> List.iter ~f: (fun (line, count) -> printf "%3d: %s\n" count line)
```

Now the few problems are

1. I ran `sudo opam install core` and after this I ran `corebuild Test.ml`.  The command did not throw any errors... but did absolutely nothing. It did not produce any binary files.
2. Since step 1 did not work I ran:

   `ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core Test.ml -o Test.byte`

   This produced a Test.byte file which I can run, but the problem is that I can go on entering lines but I cannot get the program to produce any results because it's in an infinite loop of accepting input from console.

   If I press cntl+c then the whole program terminates... again no evaluation.
3. If I run `corebuild Test.ml` again now I get an error message.

Here's the last output:

```
SANITIZE: a total of 2 files that should probably not be in your source tree
  has been found. A script shell file
  "/home/abhishek/Documents/_build/sanitize.sh" is being created. Check this
  script and run it to remove unwanted files or use other options (such as
  defining hygiene exceptions or using the -no-hygiene option).
IMPORTANT: I cannot work with leftover compiled files.
ERROR: Leftover OCaml compilation files:
  File Test.cmo in . has suffix .cmo
  File Test.cmi in . has suffix .cmi
Exiting due to hygiene violations.
```

So things are not going as said in the book. and I am having difficulty with OCaml tools and language.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `corebuild Test.byte` (for bytecode) or `corebuild Test.native` for native code.

Comment: Yes, i also recommend you to use **corebuild**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help with the first problem.

For second problem, assuming you're using some Unix-like system: enter ^D (control
D) to end your input. You can also create a file and redirect from the file:

```
$ Test.byte < my-input-file
```

Note that this is not an OCaml language problem. It's about handling files on
your system (or possibly about the command line environment).

For the third problem, remove the .cmo and .cmi files and try again, as the message suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the first question, ocamlbuild (around which corebuild is a wrapper) works by having you specify the *result* that you want. So you might have one of

```
corebuild test.byte
corebuild test.native
corebuild test.cmo
```

Where `.byte` and `.native` will specify byte-compiled and native-compiled executables, and `.cmo` will specify to just compile the file (which will be under `_build` if compilation succeeds).

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be a little late but this works on my side. I got the same output as you pasted and I ran the file `/home/abhishek/Documents/_build/sanitize.sh` to remove all "unwanted files" then I executed `corebuild freq.byte`, it works well. In your case you should run `corebuild test.byte`, I think.